# Building Android application with pgs4a fails

Tags: python, ant

For testing purposes I wanted to create a simple app with the pygame subset for android (pgs4a) witch uses ANT for building. I found an answer to that problem for windows, but I'm using Ubuntu. Installing and preparing of pgs4a and configuring of my app worked. Even `android.py test` didn't return any errors. But when I tried to build it to an apk pgs4a threw up an error:

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

Of course ant misses its buildfile, but my question is, why pgs4a doesn't generate it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is what it says — you don't have an Ant build file.

You can create one via the `android` command from the Android SDK Tools, for example:

```
android update project -p /path/to/android/project
```

Comment: Because I use pgs4a, which generates all these meta files (like `AndroidManifest.xml`) I cannot use  the android tool, which need those. Of course your answer is still showing the solution to the error, but not to the problem, which is that pgs4a doesn't generate the build.xml file.